# For a ring $A$, is $A$ Morita equivalent to $M_\infty(A)$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, morita-equivalence

Let $A$ be a ring, let $M_n(A)$ be the ring of $n$-by-$n$ matrices with elements in $A$, $A$ is Morita equivalent to $M_n(A)$, I was wondering if this also applied to infinite matrices? That is, if $A$ and $M_\infty(A)$ are Morita equivalent? Or if this is in general not true, are there cases where this happens? If at all.

Comment: What do you mean by *infinite  matrices*? Some sort of finiteness is usually required (rows, columns, both...)

Comment: For any one of the three options I mentioned, it is true that $M_\infty(M_\infty(A))$ is isomorphic to $M_\infty(A)$, so you get examples where you do have equivalence (isomorphism even!) On the other hand taking $A$ a field and column-finite matrices, for example, $M_\infty(A)$ has a non-trivial proper ideal (that of matrices with finitely many non-zero columns) while $A$ has none, so in that case you do not have a Morita equivalence.

Comment: Thanks, I mean if the ring of matrices with infinite number of columns and rows whose entries are elements from the ring $A$ (which I called $M_\infty(A)$ in this case) is Morita equivalent to $A$. I ask because I was curious.

Comment: As I said, you need to impose some finiteness conditions (for example, that there be a finite number of non-zero coefficients in each row) for otherwise you simply do not get a ring!

Comment: I guess $M_\infty(A)$ here denotes the limit/union of the $M_n(A)$.

Comment: @Garlef: you mean the colimit, and these are along non-unital maps with the result being a non-unital ring. It's not entirely clear what the correct notion of module over such a thing is (especially in this case since the corresponding non-unital ring has an approximate identity which we might want to say something about).

Comment: Thank you, in my references $M_\infty(A)$ is actually something else, which seems at first glance completely unrelated to matrices, it's just that they seem to be using the same notation used for matrix rings also, so I got carried away there, the Wikipedia entry on matrix rings mentions infinite matrices though.

Comment: Sorry, but I give -1 since the question doesn't give the intended definition of $M_{\infty}(A)$, even after all the comments by Mariano (which get a +1).

Answer (score 4):

No matter whether you mean row finite, column finite, or both the answer has to be no.  For simplicity, let $R$ be a field.  Then any of those rings has a proper 2-sided ideal consisting of the finite matrices (filled out with 0s), while the $M_n$ are all simple and a ring Morita equivalent to a simple ring is simple.